# Why this snippet is giving me incorrect line numbers?

Tags: javascript

I throw an error, and I noticed both Stackoverflow and JSFiddle giving me incorrect line numbers on stack-trace.

```js
function foo () {
 let stackTrace = (new Error()).stack;
 
 console.log(stackTrace);
}

foo();
```

Clicking on "Run code snippet" giving me this output,

```
Error
    at foo (https://stacksnippets.net/js:13:20)
    at https://stacksnippets.net/js:18:1
```

As you can see on the output, there is no `13` line on my code.

What causing this?

I'm using the Latest Chrome Browser Version.

Comment: Most likely because both of those runtime environments are sandboxed.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I've inspected JSFiddle's iFrame. It insert code into HTML by using <script> tag..

Comment: When you click on `js:13` in the console (the real one, not the one below the snippet), you'll see the line numbers. It starts counting from the beginning of the HTML, not the beginning of the `<script>` tag.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah. I'm about to write an answer which detect if return value discarded or not. This question helps that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line numbers are counted from the beginning of the file, not the beginning of the script. So when the JavaScript is in a `<script>` tag rather than an external `.js` file, the line numbers are counted from the beginning of the HTML document. This ensures that the `filename:linenumber` reference is unique when there are multiple scripts in the HTML.

Stack Snippets put the script in a tag like that, which is then loaded into an iframe, so you get the higher count.

Comment: I try to resolve line number programmatically by using "document.documentElement.innerHTML" but it gives CSS parts where Devtools doesn't.